How to Control Multiple WS2812B LED Strips Using Software PWM
I have built an electronic scoreboard consisting of 15 digits, each comprising of 7 segments of WS2812B LED strips.  With a Raspberry Pi 4B and the rpi_ws281x library I can use up to 3 GPIO pins with hardware PWM (18, 19 & 21) to control the digits - note that pins 12 & 13 are duplicates of 18 & 19, and 10 is unreliable.  This works fine most of the time, however, there are up to 504 individual connections in a single string which is rather a lot of potential points of failure.  To make the scoreboard more resilient I would like to use more of the GPIO pins.  I have read that most of the GPIO pins can utilise software PWM and that this can be used to control the WS2812B LED strips, however, I can't find any articles which explain how this can be done, along with example code.  Can you help me with this project please.  I do have some programming skills in Python and other languages but I wouldn't call myself an expert.

I do not believe software PWM can be used to drive those LEDs.  The timing is too tight.  Which model Pi?  Most I know of only have hardware PWM on 12/18 and 13/19 (for two usable channels).  Why not use an APA102 type LED?  These have a clock line and can easily be software driven.  Please edit any clarifications into your question.

You need to install the rpi_ws281x library. This library provides a Python interface to control the WS2812B LEDs.
bash

use a network of microcontrollers

Not an answer (because you don't have an answerable question) but a suggestion.
The WS2812 require precise timing which is almost impossible on a Pi although some non-standard code can control (not using PWM).
The WS2812 requires 3 pixels RGB at a speed of 800kbps.
I have had little success trying to get it to work on a modern Raspberry Pi OS.
I have used some simple code on a Pico (which is a micro controller more suited to the task). This uses one of the state machines to achieve the high speed precise timing required.
As the Pico has a PIO which can implement 8 PIO state machines so you could control up to 8 strips.
The SM timing works @ 8MHz clock to send patterns 10 clock cycles long ➡︎ 800kbps.
I modified the code to show use of 2 State Machines.
This is very simplistic and runs each strip sequentially and no attempt has been made to optimise.
# Example using PIO to drive 2 sets of WS2812 LEDs using 2SM
import array, time
from machine import Pin
import rp2

# Configure the number of WS2812 LEDs.
NUM_LEDS = 5
PIN_NUM0 = 22
PIN_NUM1 = 21
brightness = 0.2

@rp2.asm_pio(sideset_init=rp2.PIO.OUT_LOW, out_shiftdir=rp2.PIO.SHIFT_LEFT, autopull=True, pull_thresh=24)

def ws2812():
    T1 = 2
    T2 = 5
    T3 = 3
    wrap_target()
    label("bitloop")
    out(x, 1)               .side(0)    [T3 - 1]
    jmp(not_x, "do_zero")   .side(1)    [T1 - 1]
    jmp("bitloop")          .side(1)    [T2 - 1]
    label("do_zero")
    nop()                   .side(0)    [T2 - 1]
    wrap()


# Create the StateMachines with the ws2812 program, outputting on pin
sm0 = rp2.StateMachine(0, ws2812, freq=8_000_000, sideset_base=Pin(PIN_NUM0))
sm1 = rp2.StateMachine(1, ws2812, freq=8_000_000, sideset_base=Pin(PIN_NUM1))

# Start the StateMachines, which will wait for data on its FIFO.
sm0.active(1)
sm1.active(1)

# Display a pattern on the LEDs via an array of LED RGB values.
ar = array.array("I", [0 for _ in range(NUM_LEDS)])

##########################################################################
def pixels_show(sm):
    """
    Display data on sm
    """
    dimmer_ar = array.array("I", [0 for _ in range(NUM_LEDS)])
    for i,c in enumerate(ar):
        r = int(((c >> 8) & 0xFF) * brightness)
        g = int(((c >> 16) & 0xFF) * brightness)
        b = int((c & 0xFF) * brightness)
        dimmer_ar[i] = (g<<16) + (r<<8) + b
    sm.put(dimmer_ar, 8)
    time.sleep_ms(1)

def pixel_set(i, color):
    """
    Set pixel in ar
    """
    ar[i] = (color[1]<<16) + (color[0]<<8) + color[2]

def color_chase(color, wait):
    """
    Set pixel on sm1
    """
    for i in range(NUM_LEDS):
        pixel_set(i, color)
        time.sleep(wait)
        pixels_show(sm1)
    time.sleep_ms(1)
 
def wheel(pos):
    # Input a value 0 to 255 to get a color value.
    # The colours are a transition r - g - b - back to r.
    if pos < 0 or pos > 255:
        return (0, 0, 0)
    if pos < 85:
        return (255 - pos * 3, pos * 3, 0)
    if pos < 170:
        pos -= 85
        return (0, 255 - pos * 3, pos * 3)
    pos -= 170
    return (pos * 3, 0, 255 - pos * 3)
 
 
def rainbow_cycle(wait):
    """
    Display rainbow on sm0
    """
    for j in range(255):
        for i in range(NUM_LEDS):
            rc_index = (i * 256 // NUM_LEDS) + j
            pixel_set(i, wheel(rc_index & 255))
        pixels_show(sm0)
        time.sleep(wait)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 150, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
PURPLE = (180, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
COLORS = (BLACK, RED, YELLOW, GREEN, CYAN, BLUE, PURPLE, WHITE)

while(True):
    # print("chases")
    for color in COLORS:       
        color_chase(color, 0.01)

    # print("rainbow")
    rainbow_cycle(0)
time.sleep(1)

print("finished")


I think you can also use SPI to drive the LEDs. There is also this Adafruit article
